# MKViewMap custom annotation disappears on click

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm creating custom annotation for MKMap. It's work, but when I click on an annotation, the annotation disappears (see image), then the callout show and disappears too.

(I have done this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial)

Here the custom annotation :

```
class Trail: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    let title: String?
    let difficulty: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var enableInfoButton : Bool

    init(title: String, difficulty: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, enableInfoButton : Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.enableInfoButton = enableInfoButton;
        super.init()
    }

    var subtitle: String? {
        return title
    }

    func annotationView() -> MKAnnotationView {
        let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: self, reuseIdentifier: "trailPin")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.enabled = true
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        view.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -32)

        if(difficulty == Difficulty.HARD){
            view.image = UIImage(named: "ic_map_poi_trail_hard")
        }
        else if(difficulty == Difficulty.AVERAGE){
            view.image = UIImage(named: "ic_map_poi_trail_average")
        }
        else if(difficulty == Difficulty.EASY){
            view.image = UIImage(named: "ic_map_poi_trail_easy")
        }

        return view
    }

    func infoClicked(sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("infoClicked")
    }
}
```

and in the view controller :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if (annotation.isKindOfClass(Trail)) {
            let customAnnotation = annotation as? Trail
            mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("trailPin") as MKAnnotationView!

            if (annotationView == nil) {
                annotationView = customAnnotation?.annotationView()
            } else {
                annotationView.annotation = annotation;
            }

            return annotationView
        } else {
            let reuseId = "trailPin"

            var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
            if anView == nil {
                anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                anView!.image = UIImage(named:"map")
                anView!.canShowCallout = true
            }
            else {
                //we are re-using a view, update its annotation reference...
                anView!.annotation = annotation
            }

            return anView
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself, this was the line :

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I deleted it and it's work

Comment: Thanks a lot, Xero! Your answer also fixed my problem I've been struggling for a long long time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273459/ios-mkmapview-custom-images-display-on-top-left-corner/